# how to sort by count in django queryset?

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

I tried using this query but not giving expected result.

```
ships = Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte=("2016-10-22")).annotate(sku_count=Count('sku')).order_by('sku_count')
```

Comment: if I am not wrong you want to group by with 'sku' column and sort by its count is it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to group by with 'sku' column and sort by its count, this can help you.

```
# Ascending order
ships = Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte=("2016-10-22")).values("sku").annotate(sku_count=Count('sku')).order_by('sku_count')

# Descending order
ships = Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte=("2016-10-22")).values("sku").annotate(sku_count=Count('sku')).order_by('-sku_count')
```

Comment: `In [3]: ships = Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte("2016-10-22")).values("sku").annotate(sku_count=Count('sku')).order_by('sku_count')

In [5]: ships[0]
Out[5]: {'sku': u'bedcll_5rsdeal', 'sku_count': 1}
`
Instead of  **ships[0] = {'sku': u'bedcll_5rsdeal', 'sku_count': 1}** this I need object of Shipment class  so that i can proceed with further operations.

Comment: @TejasGaykar here we are doing Group by, by `sku` field thats why we are getting summaries view, if you want `Shipment` class array which have value  like 'bedcll_5rsdeal' then you have to iterate `ships` list like this:-  

`for ship in ships:
 obj=Shipment.objects.filter(sku=ship['sku'])
 #your code `

Answer (score 3):

you said in your comment above that you wanted the object. you should be able to do this:

```
ships = Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte("2016-10-22")).annotate(sku_‌​count=Count('sku')).‌​order_by('sku_count'‌​)
```

the only thing is that you will have duplicate rows for the same sku. remember that when you use 'group by', you're aggregating multiple values (Shipment instances) by a value common to them (sku).

so like Vikram said above, you can get unique skus and their count like this:

```
Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte("2016-10-22")).values(‌​"sku").annotate(sku_‌​count=Count('sku')).‌​order_by('sku_count'‌​)
```

but in order to get specific Shipment instances, you'll have to fetch Shipment instances by 'sku' at that point. HTH.

Comment: `ships=Shipment.objects.filter(added_on__gte=("2016-10-22")).annotate(sku_count =Count('sku')).order_by('sku_count')`
I Tried this, it ran without error but it does not sort by sku counts

I iterated the shipments in for loop as follows
`for ship in ships: print ship.sku`

and the output came is as follows
`BKS_100616_5MCD
samsung_LED599
BKS_2809_RBKwtch
BKS_100616_5MCD
samsung_LED599
samsung_LED599
BKS_100616_5MCD
BKS_2809_RBKwtch
samsung_LED599
`